# How do I know what size tyres can I fit on my rims?

Tags: tire, rims

I have a hybrid bike with Alex DP17 32h rims (700c).  They still have the tyres that came with the bike on them, 40c konda's, but I'd like to replace them with some puncture resistant, narrower tyres with a slick centre strip since most of my commute is on road/tarmac path.

I can't find the rims on the Alexrims site, so how do I find out what tyres it is possible to fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. measure the interior rim width (you need to remove your tyre to do this)
2. look at this chart, from Sheldon

   [image: Image of rim/tyre width table from linked Sheldon Brown page]

Comment: No need to measure, DP17's are 17mm internal width.

Comment: How do you know/find that out?  I can't find that by googling, and I have 40c's fitted as "standard" on the bike?

Comment: Update 2023 - While not wrong, that chart is now a bit old, there is more a bit more 'wriggle room' these days. e.g. https://www.wtb.com/pages/tire-rim-fit-chart